# express-session creates new cookies for each request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, express, express-session

So I'm building an app with angular on the front and nodejs/express on the backend. My problem is that when using express-session, each request creates a new session cookie.

I have searched through a lot of questions and answers but it seems that most questions that have been answered are questions regarding express 3.x, and I'm using express 4.x.

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var dbSchemas = require('./database-schemas.js');
var userDB = require('./UserDatabaseQuery');
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();

var store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/connect_mongodb_session',
    collection: 'mySessions'
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbSPPM');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'th3s3cr3tc0d30fd00m',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10
    },
    store: store,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    next();
});

app.get('/userLoggedIn', function(req, res) {
    if(req.session) {
        console.log('session cookie: \n' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
    }
    res.send({
        loggedIn: req.session.username
    });
})

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.data.username;
    var password = req.body.data.password;

    var User = mongoose.model('User', dbSchemas.userSchema);

    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatching) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    if (isMatching) {
                        res.send({
                            loggedIn: true,
                            session: req.session
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.send({
                            loggedIn: false,
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        req.session.username = username;
        console.log('created session cookie: \n' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
    });
});`
```

When i do the `console.log` i get this back:

```
created session cookie:
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":600000,"expires":"2015-10-07T11:40:34.392Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"username":"LosGlennos"}
session cookie:
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":600000,"expires":"2015-10-07T11:40:38.262Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
```

As you can see, the get and post have created two different session cookies.

I don't actually know where I'm messing up, I have read the code so many times that variable names are starting to sound funny.

**EDIT**
The thing I'm trying to accomplish is to get the session cookie created and view if the session for "LosGlennos" is expired.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Apparently, the problem does not occur when I run it on the WebView on my Android device.

Should also say that this is a cordova-application.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue today. Since the Angular code is not in the original post, I don't know for sure if you had the same problem, but I will post my solution in case it helps.

The problem I had was that POST requests do not send Cookies by default. So my sessionID was not being sent in the login request. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

To send Cookies, you can set withCredentials to true in the post operation

```
$http.post(
  '/login', 
  { 
    username: theUsername, 
    password: thePassword 
  }, 
  { 
    withCredentials: true 
  }
)
```

which is an option listed in the Angular docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

In the past I have also had sessionId naming issues, where the default name connect.sid is used by another package. I noticed that your code will default to connect.sid, so it may help to use a unique name:

```
app.use(session({
  ...
  name: 'myUniqueAppName'
}))
```